# Create rule for Merchant Name/Simple Description in Yodlee

Tags: yodlee

Occasionally Yodlee will assign an incorrect merchant name based on description text for a transaction.  For example, "APPLE RIDGE FAMILY MED" will come in as "Apple, Inc."

Is there a way to make a rule in Yodlee such that this does not happen?  I know you can assign a new category, but Description/Merchant name doesn't appear to have something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Yodlee doesn't provide any API to do so but what you can do is file a Service request using Yodlee customer care tool about this problem and Yodlee's internal team will get this fixed.